# How can I use unicode characters in perl regex substitution command?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, command-line, utf-8

This doesn't work when using unicode characters (in Ubuntu bash):

```sh
$ perl -pC -e's/[à]/a/gu' <<< 'à'
à
$ perl -pC -e's/[b]/a/gu' <<< 'b'
a
```

Even though it seems to be supported by PCRE (at least according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lOMEav/1)).

**What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some flag in the perl command?**

This "just works" in javascript, so I would be using node if I could come up with a simple one-liner for this in command line ... but I still want to know why the perl command is not working.

---

For context:

I'm trying to use substitutions like `/[àâáãä]/a/g`, `/[òôóõö]/o/g`, etc to asciify a dictionary file (i.e. remove accents, etc. of a word list), so I can use it to make spell-checking accent-insensitive (e.g. in IntelliJ Idea).

Basically these are the steps to make an "asciified" extra dictionary:

1. Download the .dic file for the language (list of all words)
2. Use grep to filter words containing non-ascii / replaceable characters
3. Use regex substitutions in succession to make words accent-insensitive
4. Import the asciified .dic file in the IDE (in addition to the standard language dictionary)

Comment: I can't repro, it's working fine for me in a freshly started Ubuntu Docker image (though I have to `bind 'set input-meta on'; bind 'set output-meta on'` to enable 8-bit I/O in Bash).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One practical approach for all of it is to use [Text::Unidecode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Unidecode)

```
perl -C -MText::Unidecode -pe'unidecode($_)'  <<< 'à'
```

Prints `a`.  The module transliterates Unicode text into plain ASCII.

Another approach: decompose characters ("normalize") using [Unicode::Normalize](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Normalize), so that the character and its [diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) (combining accents) are separated into their own code points, while they still form a valid [grapheme](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode#Extended-Grapheme-Clusters-%28Logical-characters%29), then remove the diacriticals (`\p{NonspacingMark}` or `\p{Mn}`) with a simple regex.

Both of these ways will have exceptions and edge cases but I think it may just do what you need.

---

As for code containing specific (literal) characters, need to tell Perl that the program source is then UTF-8, via the [utf8 pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8) with `use utf8;` or with a command-line flag `-Mutf8`

```
perl -C -Mutf8 -pe's/[à]/a/g' <<< 'à'
```

Comment: While working on Programming Perl, 4th Edition, @tchrist pointed out some Mac OS X problem to me where we were getting NFD input and expecting NFC, or maybe the other way around. OS interfaces are tough, and I think he may have sent me the example program written in Catalan. Good times :)  So yeah, always normalize to what you want to work with, and maybe renormalize on the way back out.

Comment: Can't believe it took me that long to notice the "de" in unidecode ... oof - I was so confused why tab completion wasn't working in apt. Anyways, for anyone that comes across this: the module can be installed in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install libtext-unidecode-perl`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `-Mutf8` to tell Perl the program is encoded using UTF-8 rather than ASCII.

```
$ perl -pC -Mutf8 -e's/[à]/a/gu' <<< 'à'
a
```

Comment: `-Mutf8` is what I was looking for. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to add `-Mutf8` to your command line.

If you're not sure how Perl is interpreting what you wrote on the command line you can make it spit it back to you with the core `B::perlstring()` function or deparse the whole script with `B::Deparse`.  That would illustrate your problem real fast.  (Enclosing the 'à' character in brackets doesn't do anything here.)

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pC -e 's/à/a/gu' <<< 'à'
```

```perl
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/\303\240/a/gu;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

See how your substitution stragely has 2 characters in it?

You can then see immediately how `use utf8` fixes your problem.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -Mutf8 -pC -e 's/à/a/gu' <<< 'à'
```

```perl
use utf8;
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/\340/a/gu;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

You can use `perlstring()` to make sure Perl is receiving the input you think.

```
$ perl -p -MB -E 'say B::perlstring($_)' <<< 'à'
"\303\240\n"
à
```

```
$ perl -pC -MB -E 'say B::perlstring($_)' <<< 'à'
"\x{e0}\n"
à
```

You can see that without `-C` Perl is receiving 2 decomposed characters.

Depending on the circumstances, Perl dumps characters as either an octal code (`\340`) or a hexadecimal code (`\xE0`).  Note well here that you can always replace raw unicode characters in your command line with the escape code version.  This is a great way to make explicit what otherwise would be ambiguous.

```
$ perl -pC -e 's/[\xE0]/a/gu' <<< 'à'
a
```

If you don't want to have to remember UTF8 mode, you can shove those options in the `PERL5OPT` environment variable or create a shell alias.  Beware of making this global!

```
$ export PERL5OPT='-C -Mutf8'
$ perl -MO=Deparse -p -e 's/à/a/gu' <<< 'à'
```

```perl
use utf8;
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/\340/a/gu;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

```
$ perl -MB -p -E 'say B::perlstring($_)' <<< 'à'
"\x{e0}\n"
à
```

Or as a shell alias.

```
alias uperl='perl -C -Mutf8'
```

See [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches) for more information on how to Swiss Army Chainsaw the command line.

See also [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I implemented steps 2 and 3.
This can be used, e.g., in [these](https://www.winedt.org/dict.html) dictionaries (though I didn't test it on every language).

`asciify-dic`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#License: "Zero-Clause BSD" <https://opensource.org/licenses/0BSD>
if [[ "$1" == "--help" ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") INPUT_FILE > OUTPUT_FILE"
  echo "Asciify a .dic file (list of dictionary words)."
  echo ""
  echo "Generates a file with ASCII-only versions of the words that have non-ASCII chars."
  echo "These additional words can be used to make spell-checking accent-insensitive."
  echo "Comment lines beginning with % are left unchanged."
  exit
fi
# Filter words containing non-ascii characters, except in comments
grep -P '^\%|[^\x00-\x7F]' $1 |
# Make words accent-insensitive, except in comments
perl -C -MText::Unidecode -pe'next if /^\s*%/;unidecode($_)' |
# Remove duplicate lines, except in comments
awk '/^\s*%/||!seen[$0]++'
```

Example usage:

```sh
asciify-dic $DIC_NAME.dic > $DIC_NAME-asciified.dic
```

Comment: Nice.  (Can first filter out comments, so other tools need not worry about them; then can also remove duplicates by piping through `uniq`)

Comment: An improvement here would be something that removes duplicates present in the original dic - i.e. when the asciified word ends up being the same as a normal word from original dict. But doing that optimization involves more complexity, and I'm satisfied with this solution now. I don't wanna get too much into perl code beyond one-liners haha

Comment: Wouldn't the final `uniq` (or your `awk`) do that?  (I see that I goofed up -- you want to skip processing comments bu leave them, not remove them.)  Btw, I didn't mean to imply more Perl :))

Comment: @zdim That `awk` only removes duplicates from the generated dic. However, there may be words that unidecode generates that are the same as in the original dic - these won't be removed, even though they aren't necessary, since it's implied that the original dic is also being used. For example, in portuguese, there is "maçã" and "maca" - both valid words. This algorithm generates "maca" as an asciified version of "maçã", but adding a word that already exists is a "waste". This may seem minor, but because of verb conjugations, there can be a lot of words like this, e.g. "cantara" and "cantará".

Comment: This optimization wouldn't do anything special, just reduce the size of the dic file (possibly by a somewhat significant amount, depending on language). Since it might not be doable with a one-liner, I thought it's probably not worth the trouble :)